# Garbage at the end of buffer socket

Tags: c++, bluetooth, winsock2

When I send `5` through a serial terminal, `recv()` outputs the sent data, and then corrupted garbage (`5╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠☺0`). This is my code:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

int i;
unsigned int aaddr[6];

void send2(string in) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    memset(&wsa, 0, sizeof(wsa));
    int error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    SOCKET btSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    SOCKADDR_BTH sockAddr;
    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
    sockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    BTH_ADDR tmpaddr = 0;
    sscanf_s("7C:9E:BD:4C:BF:B2", "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", &aaddr[0], &aaddr[1], &aaddr[2], &aaddr[3], &aaddr[4], &aaddr[5]);
    *&sockAddr.btAddr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tmpaddr = (BTH_ADDR)(aaddr[i] & 0xff);
        *&sockAddr.btAddr = ((*&sockAddr.btAddr) << 8) + tmpaddr;
    }
    connect(btSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
    char charIn[28];
    strcpy_s(charIn, in.c_str());
    send(btSocket, charIn, (int)strlen(charIn), 0);
    closesocket(btSocket);
}

void recv2() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    memset(&wsa, 0, sizeof(wsa));
    int error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    SOCKET btSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    SOCKADDR_BTH sockAddr;
    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sockAddr.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
    sockAddr.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
    BTH_ADDR tmpaddr = 0;
    sscanf_s("7C:9E:BD:4C:BF:B2", "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", &aaddr[0], &aaddr[1], &aaddr[2], &aaddr[3], &aaddr[4], &aaddr[5]);
    *&sockAddr.btAddr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        tmpaddr = (BTH_ADDR)(aaddr[i] & 0xff);
        *&sockAddr.btAddr = ((*&sockAddr.btAddr) << 8) + tmpaddr;
    }
    connect(btSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
    const int outLen = 1;
    char charOut[outLen];
    recv(btSocket, charOut, outLen, 0);
    cout << charOut;
    closesocket(btSocket);
    cout << WSAGetLastError();
}

int main() {
    recv2();
}
```

Where are all these characters coming from?

Comment: `recv()` doesn't 'output' anything. It *receives* data, and then tells you via its return code *how many bytes* of data it received, which *you* are ignoring, and *you* are printing the entire buffer regardless of how many bytes were actually received. In fact you are ignoring the return value of every system and socket call here. This is not correct systems programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should NOT reinitialize Winsock, or recreate the Bluetooth socket, on every send and read. Initialize Winsock one time, preferably at app startup. And then create 1 socket and reuse it as needed.

Also, you don't need the `charIn[]` buffer in `send2()` at all, as you can pass `in` to `send()`:

```cpp
send(btSocket, in.c_str(), (int)in.size(), 0);
```

In any case, your garbage issue is because you are not sending a null terminator after the sent data, and you are not null-terminating the buffer you are reading into, but you are displaying the buffer as if it were null-terminated. You need to pay attention to the return value of `recv()` and display only as many bytes as you actually receive, eg:

```cpp
const int outLen = 1;
char charOut[outLen+1];
int numBytes = recv(btSocket, charOut, outLen, 0);
if (numBytes > 0) {
    charOut[numBytes] = '\0';
    cout << charOut;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
const int outLen = 1;
char charOut[outLen];
int numBytes = recv(btSocket, charOut, outLen, 0);
if (numBytes > 0) {
    cout.write(charOut, numBytes);
}
```